# Two problems when I change the locale

Tags: android, locale

the code that I use to force the change:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.italiano:
            CambioIdioma.italiano(RecuperarContrasena.this, this);
            return true;
        case R.id.espanol:
            CambioIdioma.espanol(RecuperarContrasena.this, this);
            return true;
        case R.id.ingles:
            CambioIdioma.ingles(RecuperarContrasena.this, this);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class CambioIdioma extends Activity{

    public static void italiano(Context c, Activity activity ) {
        Configuration configIt = new Configuration();
        configIt.locale = Locale.ITALIAN;
        c.getResources().updateConfiguration(configIt, c.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        Intent intentIt = ((Activity)c).getIntent();
        activity.finish();
        c.startActivity(intentIt);
    }

[...]
```

the first problem: the title of the activity doesnt change (all other elements are fine)

the second problem: I've 2 layouts (portrait and landspace) and when I rotate the AVD, no matter what locale was choosen, it change to default locale

I appreciate any help, thanks in advance

Comment: That way it is a pain in the a$$, believe me, it won't work as you want, never ever, always will be glitches, like the title issue. You should consider to use the localization folders and translate the resources for the correct language. If the user uses his phone in English or Spanish they doesn't mind using your app in the phone's primary language. More detail http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: I have understood ur idea, and thanks, but I need work that way ... the I've already translated the resources.

Comment: any suggestion to solve these problems? thanks ^^

Comment: Try to change the language on every activity's onCreate method. Create a base activity and put the language change code there and extend all your activities from that base class. Also you can store the selected language index, name etc in the extended Application class and in the onCreate you select the correct language based on the index.name etc